# Wordpress wpdb prepare query with unattended " ' "

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin with a wpdb request.

When I want to publish it, the Wordpress team told me that I must prepare my querys so I test to do so

```
        $galettetable = galette_adherents;
        $result = $newdb->get_row($newdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE login_adh = %s", $galettetable, $post->user_login)) ;
```

but when I test it, the debug told me so:

```
SELECT * FROM 'galette_adherents' WHERE login_adh = 'XXXX'
```

The query I want is :

```
SELECT * FROM galette_adherents WHERE login_adh = 'XXXX'
```

Where is my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `wpdb` you should only use placeholders for string/numeric values, not table names:

```
$result = $newdb->get_row($newdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$galettetable} WHERE login_adh = %s", $post->user_login));
```

Have a look at the examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Sorry for the response time... Thks you for your help, it work fine like you said